# Can I apply individual colours from one highlight in another one?

Tags: colorscheme, highlight, highlighting

I have an auto command that changes some color scheme values so I can avoid forking them when all I need is small changes:

```
augroup FixColorSchemes
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme *
        \ highlight EndOfBuffer guibg=bg guifg=bg |
        \ highlight FoldColumn guibg=bg |
        \ highlight! link Folded FoldColumn |
        \ highlight MatchParen guibg=bg guifg=red gui=bold |
        \ highlight SpecialKey guibg=bg |
        \ highlight TermCursorNC guibg=bg guifg=bg
augroup END
```

I would like the background of the column separating vertical splits to have the same color of the `Normal` highlight's background, and its foreground to be the same color of the background of the status line (so I would get a thin line the same color of the status line). This is what I'm trying

```
\ let s:output = execute('highlight ' . 'StatusLineNC') |
\ let s:reverse = matchstr(s:output, 'inverse\|reverse') |
\ echo s:reverse |
\ let s:splitcolor = s:reverse == ''
    \ ? matchstr(s:output, 'guibg' . '=\zs\S*')
    \ : matchstr(s:output, 'guifg' . '=\zs\S*') |
\ highlight! VertSplit guibg=bg guifg=s:splitcolor
```

It seems to work, but the colour returned, although is part of the current color scheme, is not necessarily a color used in the status line. Any idea why it doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it manually and the last line gave me this error:

```
E254: Cannot allocate color s:splitcolor
```

So the `guifg` value isn't set to anything. (The `guibg` value *is* set so that may explain why you noticed some change to the VertSplit appearance.)

The problem is that this command doesn't evaluate the parameter values unlike, for example, the way `:echo s:splitcolor` will evaluate unrecognized symbols.

Scenarios like this are almost always solved by using `:exe` which will evaluate everything passed to it before executing the result.

```
:exe 'highlight! VertSplit guibg=bg guifg=' . s:splitcolor
```